# how to show double value in simple format?

Tags: java

I have some calculation like this

```
public class Florida {
public static void main(String arg[]){

    double value = 9223372036854775807l;
    double ans = 0;
            ans = ans + value * 2.00 /1000;
    System.out.println("Hello : "+ans);
  }
}
```

but I am getting answer like this

```
Hello : 1.8446744073709552E16
```

and I need in simple digit format.

Comment: Why are you using double? Wouldn't using long be simpler, or is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf()` with `%f`:

```
System.out.printf("Hello : %f\n", ans);
```

You can change the number of significant digits by tweaking the format specifier; for example, the following will just print out the integer part:

```
System.out.printf("Hello : %.0f\n", ans);
```

Comment: or write serveral numbers of floating part: System.Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000}", ans)

Answer (score 0):

Mahek, printf() and sprintf() functions will help you with that, or in general the [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class. On the given page you can also find other *printf() flags that may be very useful to you in the future. :)